# Can we say two morphisms to be isomorphic?

Tags: category-theory, terminology

The definition of subobject in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Subobject&oldid=853889121#Definitions) is this:

> let $A$ be an object of some category.  Given two monomorphisms
>
> $u : S\to A$   and   $v : T\to A$
>
> with codomain $A$, we write $u\le v$ if $u$ factors through $v$—that
>   is, if there exists $\varphi : S\to T$ such that $u = v \circ \varphi$. 
>   The binary relation $\equiv$ defined by
>
> $u\equiv v$   if and only if   $u\le v$ and $v\le u'$
>
> is an equivalence relation on the monomorphisms with codomain $A$, and
>   the corresponding equivalence classes of these monomorphisms are the
>   **subobjects** of $A$.  (Equivalently, one can define the equivalence relation by $u\equiv v$  if and only if there exists an isomorphism
>   $\varphi:S\to T$ with $u = v \circ \varphi$.)

This article doesn't assign a name to the equivalence relation $\equiv$. Can we call it *isomorphism*, and say that $u$ and $v$ are isomorphic if $u\equiv v$, or is this confusing, because isomorphism is here the morphism $\varphi$, and the adjective *isomorphic* is reserved for objects, not to morphisms? Or does this $\equiv$ relation have some another name?

Comment: You wouldn't necessarily call that equivalence relation "isomorphism" unless it was clear *in which category* they're isomorphic. Though most people would probably guess you meant in the category Shark mentions below (or suitable subcategory thereof). It doesn't have a special name in any case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call the category $\mathscr C$. Your two monomorphisms are equivalent if
$u=v\circ\varphi$ where $\varphi$ is an isomorphism. One can regard $u$ and $v$
as elements of the slice category $\mathscr{C}/A$. Then $\varphi$ is an isomorphism
in $\mathscr C$ iff it's an isomorphism in $\mathscr C/A$.
Then $u$ and $v$ are equivalent
iff they are isomorphic as elements of $\mathscr{C}/A$.

Comment: And it's worth stating the category the isomorphism lives in, since $\psi\circ u=v\circ\varphi$ gives a different notion of isomorphism of $v$ and $u$, which lives in a different category.

Comment: Finally, how can one call the equivalence relation $\equiv$ in the original category?